# Password protect apache site and all of it's content need to be protected

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have a apache hosting for use within a group of people. And I want to give individual login to those people. Additionally I want to protect entire web site including non script content with password. Is it possible to do with .htaccess and password file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done through following method.

Create password file and assign login on unix.

First time : `sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/sites-available/passwd nameofuser`

After first time : `sudo htpasswd /etc/apache2/sites-available/passwd nameofuser`

assign password to contents on the site

`sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

```
    <LocationMatch "/.*">
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Password required"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/passwd
            Require valid-user
    </LocationMatch>
```

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`